# How to create a common code module for use with cloud functions or docker

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-functions, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a typescript monorepo with front end, cloud functions, and back end (docker) packages in it. I'd like to add a "common" package that can be used by all of those.

Some production environments like Google Cloud Functions and Docker (at least in one common usage) package up the current app's directory and send it to a remote server, where it does "yarn install" to install all the dependencies.  This means the obvious ways of referencing the common package (`import * as common from "../../common"` and the like) don't work because the build server won't find `common` there.
Also, sadly, docker and GCF don't follow symlinks, so the yarn `link:` protocol isn't helpful.
And since I'm working on the common code just as much as the apps, I really don't want to publish it to a private NPM registry every time I make a change. I'd like that change process to be as seamless as possible.
The most seamless way is to just symlink `common` into each app's node_modules, but (a) yarn deletes those, and (b) the builders don't follow symlinks. So I assume I'll need *some* kind of build/push process when changing the common code.

It seems like a kind of common thing to want to abstract out common code into its own module that can be used anywhere in the monorepo, but I can't find a solution that works. (For extra points I'd like "jump to definition" in my IDE to go to the actual definition, not a local copy.) Any ideas? Can Yarn 2 help with this use case?